# Need help with a non-homogeneous Poisson Process

Tags: calculus, probability, stochastic-processes

Every day, customers arrive to a certain bank (Which opens from 10:00 AM to 3:00 PM) according to a non-homogeneous Poisson process with parameter

$$
\lambda (t) = 3 (\cos (t) +1 ), \text{ for } t \in [10, 15]
$$

a) Calculate the probability that on a given day there were more than 4 people before 1:00 p.m., knowing that there were 6 clients in total on that day.

b) Calculate the average number of clients per week, knowing that the bank is open 5 days a week, and assuming that the arrival of clients is distributed independently between different days.

Comment: You may be more likely to get help if you edit into your question what you have tried

Comment: I'm really stuck, I don't know where do I even start and there aren't many examples on the Internet :(

Comment: If you have no idea where to start with this, then probably you should learn the basics of the topic better before working on this kind of exercise.

Answer (score 0):

The average number of customers in the first three hours is $a = \int_0^3 \lambda(t) \, dt$ and the average number in the last two hours is $b = \int_3^5 \lambda(t) \, dt.$ Thus for example, the probability that there are exactly four customers in the first three hours is $\dfrac{a^3 e^{-a}}{3!}.$

The conditional probability that there were no more than four customers in the first three hours given that there were six during the whole five hours is
$$
\frac{\Pr(\text{no more than four before 1:00 and exactly six that day})}{\Pr(\text{exactly six that day})}.
$$
Let $X$ be the number of customers in the first three hours and $Y$ the number in the last two hours. Then the above is
$$
\frac{\Pr\left(\begin{array}{r} X=4\ \&\ Y=2 \\
\text{or } X=3\ \&\ Y=3 \\
\text{or } X=2\ \&\ Y=4 \\ \text{or } X=1\ \&\ Y=5 \\ \text{or } X=0 \ \&\ Y=6 \end{array} \right)}{\Pr(X+Y=6)}
$$
In the numerator you have a sum of five terms, each of which is a product of two probabilities.

Before I say more than that, you should be more forthcoming about what you do and don't already know.